# Linq to Entities - Left outer join with Lambda expression

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have this query and I can't found out how to this in Lambda expression.

```
select * from NewsVersion nv
left outer join ChangeProcess cp on cp.DocumentId = nv.NewsId and cp.EndDate is null
where nv.NewsId = 'B2301B7F-D37E-4CF5-9392-01844564BFCC'
```

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure and a bit confused about why Thomas Levesque thinks this is not an equijoin (after all NewsId == DocumentId is an equality comparison), but I don't see why this shouldn't work:

```
var query =
from nv in db.NewsVersion
join cp in db.ChangeProcess on nv.NewsId equals cp.DocumentId into joined
from j in joined.Where(x => x.EndDate == null).DefaultIfEmpty()
where nv.NewsId = "B2301B7F-D37E-4CF5-9392-01844564BFCC"
select new { NewsVersion = nv, ChangeProcess = j };
```

EDIT: corrected, according to the OP's comment

Comment: I just make a little change in your query and it's working! Thanks! from j in joined.Where(x => x.EndDate == null).DefaultIfEmpty()

Comment: Thanks, could you also mark it as the answer then? That way I get some reputation for trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not an equijoin, you can't use the `join` keyword, but you can still do it like that:

```
var query =
    from nv in db.NewsVersion
    from cp in db.ChangeProcess.Where(c => nv.NewsId == cp.DocumentId && c.EndDate == null).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where nv.NewsId = "B2301B7F-D37E-4CF5-9392-01844564BFCC"
    select new { NewsVersion = nv, ChangeProcess = cp };
```

Comment: This query will not return a newsversion if a change process end date is not null.

Comment: @sebascomeau, you're right, I missed that. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this...

```
var query =
    from nv in NewsVersion
    from cp in ChangeProcess.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where nv.NewsId == cp.DocumentId && cp.EndDate == null && 
       nv.NewsId = "B2301B7F-D37E-4CF5-9392-01844564BFCC"
    select new { ... }
```

Comment: This query will not return a newsversion if a change process end date is not null.